# How many symbols are in an alphabet if there are two symbols that mean the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If you were to define a formal alphabet as the set {a, b}, but also say "a = b," then does the alphabet contain 1 symbol or 2 symbols? On the one hand, it seems like it should contain 2 symbols since they are two distinct symbols syntactically. Semantically, the 2 symbols are the same thing, so the set contains one thing, although the "thing" in mind may not be symbols per se.

Note: I'm assuming this is a different issue from token vs symbol distinction, since saying multiple tokens of a symbol doesn't mean there are more than 1 symbol is different from asking if 2 symbols being equal in some sense makes it 1 or 2 symbols.

Comment: In which context are you writing $a=b$ if $\{a,b\}$ is an alphabet? Could you give an example or a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer I got from user keitamaki on Reddit that seems perfect to me.

> If your formal alphabet is {a,b}, then "a=b" isn't a string in your formal language (since '=' isn't in your formal alphabet).
>
> So if you're saying "a=b", then you're making that statement in the meta-language. And if you literally mean by that that a and b are the same symbol, then yes, your formal alphabet is just {a}.
>
> But perhaps the better answer is: "don't do that" :)
>
> If you define your formal alphabet as {a,b}, then it is usually understood that a and b are different symbols. If you then go on to say (in the meta-language) that a and b are the same symbol, this isn't an issue of semantics at all (again, because "a=b" doesn't have a semantic meaning inside your formal language, you won't be writing truth tables for "a=b" and you won't be talking about models of that statement because it isn't a statement in your language). It's literally you saying that: "oh, by the way, when I wrote "a" and "b" earlier in my definition, I didn't mean to."

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a symbol and the object that the symbol represents. When we say $a=b$, we don't mean to say that the symbols are the same, but rather that the object represented by $a$ is the same object as the object represented by $b$. The symbols $a$ and $b$ themselves are still different symbols.

In short: just because two symbols *mean* the same thing doesn't mean that they *are* the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The symbols in a formal alphabet don't "mean" anything.
They just exist.

If you say your alphabet is $\{ a, b\}$, one interpretation (I think the usual one) is that the symbol $a$ in this set literally represents the lower-case letter $a$.
Likewise $b$ represents the lower-case letter $b$.
In that case, $a \neq b.$

On the other hand, let's suppose your meaning when you write $\{ a, b\}$
is, "I have a single symbol of an alphabet, I'm not saying what symbol yet, but it is the value of a variable named $a$; and I have a single symbol of an alphabet, I'm not saying what symbol yet, but it is the value of a variable named $b$."
This is akin to the situation where someone says $x$ is an integer, $y$ is an integer, and $\{x,y\}$ is a set; then the cardinality of the set depends on whether $x = y.$
If you say $a=b,$ you have just told us new information about the variables named $a$ and $b,$ namely that each is assigned to the same symbol of an alphabet,
and therefore your alphabet contains one symbol.
Or you could tell us that $a \neq b,$ in which case your alphabet has two symbols.

It's unclear to me what the usefulness is in listing the symbols of an alphabet using variables whose assignments to actual symbols are unstated (and possibly redundant)
rather than literally using the actual symbols of the alphabet.
There are cases where it could be useful to make a one-to-one substitution of one alphabet for another: for example, when I write the string $abaabbba$ in this answer, my computer monitor (and probably yours too) has to manipulate a large number of pixels to render each $a$ or $b$, whereas each of those symbols is represented by just a small multiple of eight bits in a server somewhere.
But in that case the integrity of the exercise depends upon the different encodings in the server *not* representing the same glyphs on the computer monitor.